# Append current category name to product title on woocommerce category archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

I would like to display the current category in the product name in woocommerce. What only applies for variable products.

The code below is partly working, but need some reforming:

1 - to be applied for only for variable products.

2 - to show the current category that the viewer is in not the main product category.

```
remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10);
function loop_title() { 
global $post;?>
<div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="feed-item-baslik"><?php the_title(); ?> <?php 
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            echo $terms[0]->name;
        }?>
    <?php endif;?></a></h2>

</div>
<?php }
add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'loop_title', 10);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** The following should work as you are expecting:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_shop_loop_item_title', 5 );
function custom_shop_loop_item_title() {
    global $product;

    if ( $product->is_type('variable') && is_product_category() ) {
        remove_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_title', 10);
        add_action('woocommerce_shop_loop_item_title', 'custom_product_loop_title', 10);
    }
}

function custom_product_loop_title() {
    $taxonomy       = 'product_cat';
    $queried_object = get_queried_object();
    ?>
    <div class="col-xl-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="feed-item-baslik"><?php the_title();
        // For product category archives pages
        if( is_a($queried_object, 'WP_Term') && $queried_object->taxonomy === $taxonomy ) {
            echo ' ' . $queried_object->name;
        }
        ?></a></h2>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! The only problem is that, other single product names are somehow disappeared completly from the category pages.

Comment: The code drops some error "Syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting T_ENDIF" at line 8.

Comment: @Qwertzui11 Ok sorry multiple updates… It works just fine this time.

Comment: Nice job! Thanks for that!